# Detect you are running from Android for Work container?

Tags: android

How do I detect if my app is running from the Android for work container?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
int userId = Process.myUid()/100000;
```

*userId* will hold an int that represent the current user ID the application is running under.

For example:

- In the case the application is running under the device's 'owner',
  *userId* will be 0.
- In the case the application is running under the work profile of the
  'owner' user, *userId* will be 10.

---

If your application is compiled as part of the Android framework and it has access to hidden APIs, use the following:

```
int userId = UserHandle.myUserId()
```